# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC : sending selected checkboxes to controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have following list view with checkboxes:

```
@model IEnumerable<PaketServisAracTakip.Models.Item>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Yükleme Yap";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2 class="text-center text-success">@ViewBag.name İsimli Araca Yükleme Yap</h2>

<form asp-controller="Vehicle"
      asp-action="LoadItem" method="post">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Oluştur" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">
                Yüklensin mi?
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="@item.Id" asp-validation-for="@item.Id"></label>
                        <input class="form-check-input" name="ids" type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" id="@item.Id">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    ₺@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my item model with database integrated:

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "İsim")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="{0} alanı boş bırakılamaz.")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage ="İsim 50 karakteri geçemez.")]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Fiyat")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} alanı boş bırakılamaz.")]
        [Range(0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 0 girmelisin.")]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Açıklama")]
        public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzYZe.png)

So when button is clicked i want to get checked items in my controller. I tried this but its empty:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadItem(IEnumerable<Item> model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I also tried int array and FormCollection but didn't work. I think I need some tag helpers but don't know which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when button is clicked i want to get checked items in my controller. I
> tried this but its empty

Please check the code in the View Page, since the table doesn't in the `<form>` element, when you click the `Submit` button, the submitted form doesn't contain the related data.

Besides, to submit the model data to the controller using model binding, we should use the `@for` statement to loop through the entities and use hidden fields to store the related data. Please refer the following sample and change your code:

Model:

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "İsim")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} alanı boş bırakılamaz.")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "İsim 50 karakteri geçemez.")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fiyat")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} alanı boş bırakılamaz.")]
    [Range(0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 0 girmelisin.")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Açıklama")]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsChecked { get; set; } //add a property to store whether the item is check or not.
}
```

View page:

```
@model List<netcore3_1sample.Models.Item>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ItemIndex";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
 
<h2 class="text-center text-success">@ViewBag.name İsimli Araca Yükleme Yap</h2>

<form asp-controller="Home"
      asp-action="LoadItem" method="post">
    <br /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Oluştur" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">
                    Yüklensin mi?
                </th>
                <th class="text-center">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th class="text-center">
                    Price
                </th>
                <th class="text-center">
                    Description
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            @for( var i = 0; i < Model.Count;i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="@Model[i].Id" asp-validation-for="@Model[i].Id"></label>
                            <input class="form-check-input" name="ids" type="checkbox" value="@Model[i].Id" id="@Model[i].Id">
                            @*<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model[i].IsChecked" />*@
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Name)
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Name" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ₺@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Price)
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Price" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Description)
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Description" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Code in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadItem(List<Item> model, int[] ids)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ItemIndex");
    }
```

According to your code, you are using a html checkbox element to store the selected Item ID, so here we need to add an array to get the selected ids.

Besides, you could add a `IsChecked` property in the Item model, then change the following code:

```
    <input class="form-check-input" name="ids" type="checkbox" value="@Model[i].Id" id="@Model[i].Id">
```

to

```
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model[i].IsChecked" />
```

By using this method, in the controller, you could filter the selected item based on the IsChecked property.

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks i solved issue with this but what is the difference with for and foreach in this situation?

Comment: I have checked both `for` and `foreach` statement, it seems that when using `foreach` statement, after submitting the form, the data will be null in the controller. But if using `for`  statement, we could get the submitted model.

Comment: Yeah i tested foreach first and didn't work, weird.